# Remove-AzResourceGroup - Long running operation failed with status 'Conflict'

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-resource-manager, azure-powershell

We have a fairly common occurrence of the `Remove-AzResourceGroup` cmdlet failing with a conflict error. Deleting a resource group with no active locks should really never fail. None of the target resource groups are empty when this fails.

This is causing our non-production clean up process to fail and increase the spend for the given Azure Subscription.

```bsh
»  Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName my-rg | Group-Object -Property ResourceType | select -Property Count, Name | ft -AutoSize

Count Name
----- ----
    1 microsoft.alertsmanagement/smartDetectorAlertRules
    1 Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts
    1 Microsoft.Insights/components
    7 microsoft.insights/metricalerts
    7 microsoft.insights/webtests
    1 Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways
    1 Microsoft.Network/networkProfiles
    1 Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses
    1 Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks
    1 Microsoft.NotificationHubs/namespaces
    1 Microsoft.NotificationHubs/namespaces/notificationHubs
    1 Microsoft.Portal/dashboards
    1 Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces
    1 Microsoft.SignalRService/SignalR
    1 Microsoft.Sql/servers
    3 Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases
    4 Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts
    1 Microsoft.Web/certificates
    8 Microsoft.Web/serverFarms
    8 Microsoft.Web/sites
```

Comment: Are there some resources in the group? If so, what are they? Please check it in the portal, choose the `Show hidden types` option, then show the screenshot here.

Comment: Why was this closed, Azure Support asked me to post this hear and there has been zero movement on this question.

Comment: @MotoWilliams, closed(closed reason: need more details) because you didn't answer the comment for a long time. And also please @ somebody when you update the question. Thank you.

Comment: I updated the contents of the question the same day the comment asked about the RG contents.